# Can not implicitly convert type 'Android.Widget.ImageView

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have the following problem:

> Error CS0029 Can not implicitly convert type 'Android.Widget.ImageView
>   [*, *, *]' to 'Android.Widget.ImageView []'

```
ImageView[] MyImagen = new ImageView [
            Resource.Drawable.uno,
            Resource.Drawable.dos,
            Resource.Drawable.tres
            ];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solve it as follows

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        int numero, numero2;
        ImageView imagen1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice1);
        ImageView imagen2 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_Dice2);

        Button botonP = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRoll);

        Random ran = new Random();

        int[] myImage = {
            Resource.Drawable.uno,
            Resource.Drawable.dos,
            Resource.Drawable.tres,
            Resource.Drawable.cuatro,
            Resource.Drawable.cinco,
            Resource.Drawable.seis
        };


        botonP.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {

            numero = ran.Next(0, 6);

            numero2 = ran.Next(0, 6);
            Console.WriteLine(numero + " " + numero2);
            imagen1.SetImageResource(myImage[numero]);
            imagen2.SetImageResource(myImage[numero2]);

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageView[] MyImagen = new ImageView[] {
        Resource.Drawable.uno,
        Resource.Drawable.dos,
        Resource.Drawable.tres
        };
```

Previously you were defining the variable as a three dimensional array `ImageView[,,]`, which is not assignable to an `ImageView[]`.